# Time complexity to solve Discrete log problem

Tags: public-key

What is the time to complexity to solve
Discrete log  problem now in $Z_p$?

Initially for $n$ bit prime $p$, it was $Exp(n^{1/3})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days the fastest general method to solve discrete logarithms modulo primes is the [number field sieve](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~psh/ANTproc/12oliver.pdf), which has the asymptotic complexity

$$
e^{(1.92+o(1)) (\log p)^{1/3} (\log\log p)^{2/3}}
$$

Comment: Note that this is a *heuristic* asymptotic complexity, not a proven one.

Comment: You're right, of course. Given it's little-oh, that factor can actually be any function, as long as it becomes insignificant at infinity input sizes.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formula (save for the dots after 1.92). Notice that the little-oh in the exponent makes it impossible to give a big-Oh expression for the complexity. If that $o(1)$ is taken to be $0.01$, the effort is raised by $37\%$ for $1024$-bit $p$, and $52\%$ for $2048$-bit $p$.